# In x64, how gcc decides the order of parameter passing?

Tags: gcc, parameter-passing, 64-bit

I learn that registers are used to pass parameters between caller function and callee function in x64. The first parameter is passed through register rdi. The second parameter is passed through register rsi. Then rdx ,rcx, r8, r9. However, an interesting phenomenon I observed is that gcc has no uniform idea about which parameter should get passed first. Given that function A and function B will call function C and function C has three parameters c1, c2, c3.

In function A, you will see:

```
mov rdi, c1
mov rsi, c2
mov rdx, c3
call C
```

However, in function B, you will see:

```
mov rsi c2
mov rdi c1
mov rdx c3
call C
```

So, my question is how gcc decides the order of parameter passing? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You mean "order of instructions issued"? Most likely the surrounding code cause instructions scheduler and registers allocator to rearrange instructions (rdi is still busy, we don't want to wait, lets start with rsi)

Comment: Thanks Severin for vivid example of instruction scheduler. Do you have any idea about which optimization option of gcc would result in such scheduling optimization? Thanks again.

Comment: Well, -O3 will turn pretty much anything on. But other part of the equation is particular hardware you're optimizing for - check gcc docs for `-mtune` and `-march` options, and `-mtune` in particular - it will actually affects scheduling